# How to use Tesseract with OpenCV in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I want to use Tesseract with OpenCV and Visual Studio

How can I change this line of command to lines of codes written on C++

```
tesseract imagexx.tiff out
```